# how to deal with very slow training in keras?

Tags: numpy, memory, keras, wavelet, pyhook

**The story**
I have a data-set of ECG signal recordings which is shaped (162 patient,65635 sample), and I got  the continuous wavelet transform of these recording so that the result is shaped(162 patient,65635 sample, 80 coefficient) which is very large to fit in memory (40 MB) so I saved each instance of these as .npz matrix and used keras generators in training, I use LSTM, and convolution layrs and CPU and the training is very slow.

**Questions**

1. what are the best strategies to deal with this  problem?
2. how to decrease the size of the coefficient matrix resulting from cwt?

Comment: Instead of loading the entire dataset onto memory, how about streaming portions of data on the go using something like an [ImageDataGeneator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator)? Also, note that using CPU to train deep neural networks take a lot of time. If you want to prioritize speed, use cloud platforms such as AWS which make use of GPU computing power.

Comment: I use a custom keras generator to load the data as patches, and  it turned out to be that the long sequence ( 65635 LSTM) is the main cause of this slow down